# How to always execute a piece of code when I enter in my app?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

I need to initialize the app's SQLite database every time I enter in the app, from any activity (not only from the launcher activity).

My app has `alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` but this flag seems to have no effect on my database, which is stored in the assets folder.

How to always execute a piece of code when I enter in my app?

Comment: "I need to initialize the app's SQLite database every time I enter in the app, from any activity (not only from the launcher activity)" -- that makes no sense to me. If you will be destroying the user's data on pretty much every operation (e.g., user is in your app, takes a phone call, returns, and you destroy the data), why are you bothering with saving the data in the first place? Just "initialize the app's SQLite database" when you first run the app and never touch it again.

Comment: The problem is that when I exit from my application from an activity different from the launcher, once I return in it my database is null, so that I must re-initialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). That one exists the whole lifecycle of your app.